# Dynamically generate directive based on $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I would like to dynamically generate directive based on the $watch. Here is my code that simply logs the value of the service object:

```
  gasStation.directive('createMenuTree', ['customerType', function (customerType) {
    console.log(customerType.getCustomerType() + ' enterring a directive');
    var template;


    console.log(customerType.getCustomerType() + ' from directive');

    var linker = function(scope){console.log()}

    return {

        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {}],

        link: function(scope){
            scope.$watch(function(){
                console.log(customerType.getCustomerType() + ' watcher');
                if (customerType.getCustomerType() == 'REGULAR') {
                    template = 'dashboard/regular_dashboard.html';
                }
                if (customerType.getCustomerType() == 'BUSINESS') {
                    template = 'dashboard/business_dashboard.html';
                }
                return customerType.getCustomerType();
            });
        },

        templateUrl: template
    };
}]);
```

How I am using the directive : `<create-menu-tree></create-menu-tree>`

The question is: how can I set the `templateUrl` variable based on the `customerType.getCustomerType()` value? Currently ,the value of the `template` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http` service to dynamically get html string based on customer type in directive link function, then use `$compile` to bind the html string with your scope, finally replace `<create-menu-tree>` contents with new compiled element

```
gasStation.directive('createMenuTree', ['customerType', '$compile', '$http', 

function (customerType, $compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        template: '',
        scope:false,
        compile: function(){
            return {
               pre: function(scope, element, attr){

                   var templateUrl = '';

                   if (customerType.getCustomerType() == 'REGULAR') {
                      templateUrl = 'dashboard/regular_dashboard.html';
                   }
                   if (customerType.getCustomerType() == 'BUSINESS') {
                      templateUrl  = 'dashboard/business_dashboard.html';
                   }

                   $http.get(templateUrl).then(function(htmlString){
                        var templateEle = $compile(htmlString)(scope);
                        element.empty();
                        element.append(tempalteEle);
                   })

               },
               post: function(scope, element, attr){}
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to avoid using  $http service? It might be overkill to use ...

Comment: Yes, you can avoid using `$http`. It based on where you store your template.Here I suppose you put the template in a separate html file. You can use [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) to store and fetch template

Comment: Ok, got your point. One more question: I don't understand what is the following variable element ? Where does it come from?

Comment: when link function called, angular injects `$element` service into the function, `$element` represents the element where the directive to be used, check the [$compile api doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: Ok, understood about variable. Meanwhile, I have got the following error while trying your approach: ` TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`